# naudio DataAvailable compile error

Tags: c#, vb.net, naudio

I am trying to understand why this code below (**waveInStream.DataAvailable**):

```
Private Sub cmbRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim saveFileDialog As New SaveFileDialog()
    saveFileDialog.Title = "Select output file:"
    saveFileDialog.Filter = "WAV Files (*.wav)|*.wav"
    saveFileDialog.FileName = outputFilename

    If saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        outputFilename = saveFileDialog.FileName

        waveInStream = New WaveIn(44100, 2)
        writer = New WaveFileWriter(outputFilename, waveInStream.WaveFormat)
        waveInStream.DataAvailable += New EventHandler(Of WaveInEventArgs)(AddressOf waveInStream_DataAvailable)
        waveInStream.StartRecording()


        ' Just controling the objects on the screen.
        cmbRecord.Enabled = False
        cmbStop.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Is giving me the error:

```
Error 1 'Public Event DataAvailable(sender As Object, e As NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs)'
is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.
```

I am converting the code above from c# to VB.net using the examples [HERE](http://naudio.codeplex.com/)

The c# that was converted to VB is this:

```
private void cmbRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog.Title = "Select output file:";
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "WAV Files (*.wav)|*.wav";
        saveFileDialog.FileName = outputFilename;
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            outputFilename = saveFileDialog.FileName;

            waveInStream = new WaveIn(44100,2);
            writer = new WaveFileWriter(outputFilename, waveInStream.WaveFormat);

            waveInStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveInStream_DataAvailable);
            waveInStream.StartRecording();


            // Just controling the objects on the screen.
            cmbRecord.Enabled = false;
            cmbStop.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
waveInStream.DataAvailable += New EventHandler(Of WaveInEventArgs)(AddressOf waveInStream_DataAvailable)
```

with

```
AddHandler waveInStream.DataAvailable, AddressOf waveInStream_DataAvailable
```

Comment: You got it, keyboardP. Thanks!